# Deserialize json object that contains another object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize this json file:

```
{
   "result":
     {
        "car1":{"lat":37.989728,"long":23.664633},
        "car2":{"lat":38.008027,"long":23.774068}
     }
}
```

I have tried like this:

```
public static void parseJson(string data)
{
     Result all = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(data);  
}

public class Result
{
     public Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
     public string lat { get; set; }
     public string lon { get; set; }
}
```

But the object `all` remains null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you need if you make your classes like this:

```
class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public Dictionary<string, Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

class Car
{
    public decimal Lat { get; set; }
    public decimal Long { get; set; }
}
```

Here's an example program demonstrating:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
           ""result"":
             {
                ""car1"":{""lat"":37.989728,""long"":23.664633},
                ""car2"":{""lat"":38.008027,""long"":23.774068}
             }
        }";

        Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Car> kvp in result.Cars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": lat=" + kvp.Value.Lat + 
                                        ", long=" + kvp.Value.Long);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output of the above:

```
car1: lat=37.989728, long=23.664633
car2: lat=38.008027, long=23.774068
```

Answer (score 2):

The object in your JSON has two properties, `car1` and `car2`, and so the class you're mapping it to (`Result`) should have those two properties:

```
public class Result
{
     public Car car1 { get; set; }
     public Car car2 { get; set; }
}
```

---

Re your comment below:

> Ok but those two cars are an example. In reality the number of cars will vary each time I fetch the json

In that case, the JSON has to change to use an array:

```
{
   "result":
     {
        cars: [
            {"lat":37.989728,"long":23.664633},
            {"lat":38.008027,"long":23.774068}
        ]
     }
}
```

And then I think the `Result` class should be:

```
public class Result
{
     public List<Car> cars { get; set; }
}
```

or possibly

```
public class Result
{
     public Car[] cars { get; set; }
}
```

(You might be able to get rid of the intermediate object, if you don't have anything on it other than the cars.)

Comment: Ok but those two cars are an example. In reality the number of cars will vary each time I fetch the json. How can I manage this?

Comment: @jayt.dev: In that case, you'll want an array in the JSON rather than discrete properties. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But json is a response from an http request to an API so i cannot change it. I have to figure out how to handle the existing format.

Comment: @jayt.dev: That is a seriously broken API. Unfortunately, I think you'll have to write code using the raw JSON objects that JSON.Net provides. I did that a couple of years back, but I don't recall the details. You won't get automatic mapping to a class, because you can't define the class if you don't know how many `carX` properties there will be.

Comment: What if i create another class Coordinates 
{
    lat {get set}
    lon {get set}
}
And in Cars have public Coordinates Coordinates

Comment: @jayt.dev: I don't see that that would help anything, `result` doesn't have coordinates, it has properties that refer to objects that have coordinates. The fundamental issue is that the JSON defines an object (assigned to `result`) that has more than one property (`car1`, `car2`, etc.) which you've said will vary from call to call. That's rubbish API design. The correct thing here is to tell them to fix it. Barring that, as I said, you'll have to use the relatively "raw" parts of JSON.Net rather than the bits that do nice mappings for you.

Answer (score 0):

refer The below Code Snippet Hope it may Help you !!!

```
class WeapsCollection
{
    public Dictionary<string, WeaponDetails> Weapons { get; set; }

}

class WeaponList
{
    public WeaponDetails AEK { get; set; }
    public WeaponDetails XM8 { get; set; }
}

class WeaponDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Kills { get; set; }
    public int Shots_Fired { get; set; }
    public int Shots_Hit { get; set; }
}

class Program  
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
           'weapons':

                    {
                       'aek':
                            {
                               'name':'AEK-971 Vintovka',
                               'kills':47,
                               'shots_fired':5406,
                               'shots_hit':858
                            },
                       'xm8':
                            {
                               'name':'XM8 Prototype',
                               'kills':133,
                               'shots_fired':10170,
                               'shots_hit':1790
                            },
                    }

        }";

        WeapsCollection weps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeapsCollection>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(weps.Weapons.First().Value.Shots_Fired);            

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Won't help. You ve got 2 weapons but as i described above the number of my "weapons" vary